# Wordpress Redirecting Non Category Pages /page/nnn to their Canonical URLs

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, rel-canonical

I seemingly to have a strange issue I have found in almost every other Wordpress site.

Suppose, you have set your Blog home to a static WP page `/myhome`. And you have a separate page for blog `/blog`.

Now, this works fine and should be:

```
/blog
/blog/page/2
/blog/page/3
/blog/page/4
```

But, for all other pages, e.g. `/about-us`, these links also work:

```
/about-us/page/2
/about-us/page/3
/about-us/page/4
```

And show the content of the `/about-us` page.

My problem is that `/about-us/page/2` should ideally redirect to `/about-us` (it's canonical URL) since there are no paginations in any other page except the `/blog`.

What am I missing there ? This seems to happen on almost all sites I have checked and is really frustrating from SEO point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design and intentional. WordPress rewrites have become increasingly complex over the years, and many plugins utilise the `page` endpoint for a page (usually with a template and custom query) - redirecting introduces a potential world of pain.

Long story short, it doesn't matter anyway. WordPress adds [`<link rel="canonical />`](https://moz.com/learn/seo/duplicate-content) for pages, so no need to worry over duplicate content.

**Update:** For localised situations where you want to disregard the potential risks, this will canonicalize all page URLS - note that it does not check if a page is actually paginated (i.e. with the `<!--nextpage-->` quicktag) and will break this feature if you use it.

```
function wpse_199180_canonical_pages( $wp ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_page() && isset( $wp->query_vars['paged'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_queried_object() ), 301 );
        exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'wp', 'wpse_199180_canonical_pages' );
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I know it's adding <link canonical> correctly. But, my client becomes angry when his homepage is opening from `example.com/page/12345` and any number on that.

Comment: For an isolated solution see my revised answer.

Comment: Wow, that `UPDATE` answer works perfect. Can you please post your answer to my SO question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066407/wordpress-redirecting-non-category-pages-page-nnn-to-their-canonical-urls And I will reward the bounty to you.